# Há alguma diferença entre um evento com passagem de parâmetros para um sem passagem?

Tags: jquery

Considerando:

**jQuery**

```
$("#seletor1").on("click", function(){
    $("#seletor2").trigger("click", {dados: "informação"});
});
$("#seletor2").on("click", function(){
    //faça coisas
});
$("#seletor2").on("click", function(evento, dados){
    //faça coisas
});
```

Qual ele vai acionar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ambos serão acionados](http://jsfiddle.net/bfavaretto/95R3f/). A passagem dos parâmetros é determinada por quem emite o evento, e não pela sua nomeação nos listeners. Portanto o primeiro parâmetro (objeto evento) é sempre passado pelo jQuery, independente se ele está nomeado no seu listener ou não.

No primeiro caso, `evento` e `dados` ainda poderão ser acessados via `arguments[0]` e `arguments[1]` respectivamente:

```
$("#seletor2").on("click", function(){
    var evento = arguments[0];
    var dados = arguments[1];
});
```

No seu segundo listener, as variáveis não precisam ser definidas pois os parâmetros já vêm nomeados, mas o objeto `arguments` também está disponível:

```
$("#seletor2").on("click", function(evento, dados){
    console.log(evento === arguments[0]); // true
    console.log(dados === arguments[1]); // true
});
```

Comment: Poderia dar algum exemplo de codificação usando `arguments[x]` ou isso sairia do escopo da pergunta? Dei uma procurada pela internet e não encontrei nada muito relevante.

Comment: Reorganizei a resposta e coloquei um exemplo, veja se ficou mais claro. Está no escopo da pergunta sim.

Comment: Então arguments é como se fosse um array de argumentos? Quero dizer, posso usar diretamente `arguments[x]`?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Os argumentos têm índices numéricos e a quantidade total pode ser obtida em `arguments.length`. Porém não é uma array de verdade, é um objeto "disfarçado".

Comment: No exemplo de código na pergunta, um objeto está sendo passado como parâmetro; a forma de pegar o valor "informação" desse objeto seria `arguments[1].dados`?

Comment: É, `arguments[1].dados`, ou `dados.dados` no segundo exemplo. Aliás, é preferível usar argumentos nomeados sempre que possível.